# How can I get a new Fedora 19 install to boot on Intel NUC

Tags: fedora, boot, uefi

I have a newly installed Fedora 19 on an Intel NUC computer.   During installation, I selected the "reclaim all space" option and took the default partitioning.
The install created an EFI boot partition, but the BIOS on the computer does not seem to recognize it.   I can boot Fedora Live from a USB stick and mount the partitions without issue.

If the UEFI boot and Legacy boot options are both selected, the BIOS displays

```
Reboot and Select proper Boot device
or Insert Boot Media in selected Boot device and press a key.
```

If either of the options are unchecked:

```
A bootable device has not been detected.
Please refer to the Product Guide at http://support.interl.com/support/motherboards/desktop
```

I did not find any helpful info at the URL above...

Here is the partition table:

```
Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1            2048          411647   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          411648         1435647   500.0 MiB   0700  
   3         1435648       234440703   111.1 GiB   8E00
```

And the details on partition 1:

```
Partition number (1-3): 1
Partition GUID code: C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B (EFI System)
Partition unique GUID: C81832BE-6B66-474C-99B3-8C4DF9654B93
First sector: 2048 (at 1024.0 KiB)
Last sector: 411647 (at 201.0 MiB)
Partition size: 409600 sectors (200.0 MiB)
Attribute flags: 0000000000000000
Partition name: 'EFI System Partition'
```

I've been unsuccessful in finding details that match this particular scenario

Here is the output from efibootmgr after booting from the USB stick.

```
# efibootmgr
BootCurrent: 0004
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0002,0003,0004,0000
Boot0000* Fedora
Boot0001* SATA : PORT 0 : Crucial_CT120M500SSD3 : PART 0 : Boot Drive
Boot0002* USB : Generic SD/MMC/MS/xD 1.07
Boot0003* USB : Generic MicroSD/M2 1.08 : PART 1 : Boot Drive
Boot0004* UEFI : USB : Generic MicroSD/M2 1.08 : PART 0 : OS Bootloader
```

Ideally, I'd like to be able to boot directly from the SATA drive, but at this point, I'd also be open to a solution that has a multi-stage boot using a USB stick -- as long as the root partition is on the SATA drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this by booting the Fedora 19 Live CD with UEFI disabled (i.e., only Legacy Boot enabled), and reinstalling F19, which created an MBR configuration.
I don't have UEFI, but I do have a bootable install.

Comment: This also applied to a NUC installation of Fedora 22. @TomG saves the day!